# ¿Como realizar una matriz que ya contenga datos?

Tags: java

En mi examen me decía que con los valores que contenía la tabla que estaba impresa en una hoja obtuviera un arreglo con sus porcentajes mi pregunta es como creo una matriz con esos mismos valores para después poner porcentajes en un arreglo.
-Java

Comment: Hola @Marc, bienvenido a SOes. ¿Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora? Hace falta ver tu código para poder ayudarte. Ver si tienes fallos, si te has atascado en un punto... Puedes leer [ask] para ver como rehacer tu pregunta.

Comment: Muchos no le vemos problema a eso, por favor comparte que has intentado, tal vez descubras que es trivial o tal vez encuentres dudas que valga la pena compartir si lo intentas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buenas Mark :)

Para declarar un arreglo unidimencional (tabla de solo un renglón) podría ser de la siguiente manera:

```
int arreglo[] = {4,3,35,-1,2000}; //Aquí van los valores de tu tabla
```

si lo quieres mostrar en pantalla puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
for(int i = 0; i<arreglo.length; i++){ 
    System.out.print(arreglo[i] + ", ");
}
//arreglo.length devuelve la cantidad de datos en el arreglo
```

Sin embargo si lo que quieres es una matriz o arreglo bidimencional (tabla con uno o varios renglones y columnas) podrías utilizar:

```
int tabla[][] = {
                    { 95, 45, 37, 70, 85 },
                    { -4, 10, 92, 49, 48 },
                    { 2, 30, 51, 100, -9 }
                 };
//Se puede poner en una sola línea de código, pero así es un poco más visual
```

Donde todo va dentro de unos {} principales, y utilizarás los corchetes {} una vez más para ingresar cada dato de cada renglón.

Los datos van separados por comas , y también cada renglón, excepto el último.

[image: comas en un Arreglo]

Y para mostrar tus datos ingresados, podrías usar el siguiente código:

```
for(int i = 0; i<tabla.length; i++){ //Al ser Bidimensional, tabla.length = 2;
        for(int j = 0; j<tabla[i].length; j++){          
            System.out.print(tabla[i][j] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Por último, debo decir que cada renglón puede tener su propia cantidad de datos (no tiene porque ser simétrica la tabla).

```
//Ejemplo de Arreglo bidimencional no simétrico.
int tabla[][] = {
                    { 95, 1, 35, 7, 85 },
                    { 4, 3, 5, 1, -4, 5, 56, 92 },
                    { 2, 30 },
                    { -5, 23, 48 }
                 };
```

Saludos :)